# Can I rely on a backwards range in kotlin not executing for loop?

Tags: kotlin, range

Is it a good idea to rely on a backwards range in Kotlin (e.g. `10..0`) not executing a for loop?

Consider this example:

```
val arr = arrayOf(1,2,3)
val level = 0
for (i in arr.indices) {
    for (j in i + 1..level) {
        //never runs
    }
}
```

I assume there specifically being the `downTo` operator means relying on this is ok, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. A range created by `0..10` is a completely empty range, so looping over it will do nothing.

From the docs of [`rangeTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html):

> ```
> operator fun <T : Comparable<T>> T.rangeTo(
>     that: T
> ): ClosedRange<T>
> ```
>
> Creates a range from this Comparable value to the specified `that` value.
>
> This value needs to be smaller than `that` value, otherwise the returned range will be empty.

(You can dig down into its implementation, specifically to `IntProgressionIterator`, where you'll see that there'll be nothing to iterate on if `start > end`.)

Comment: While checking the implementation is often helpful, I don't think it's a good answer to this question.  **The issue is whether this particular aspect of its behaviour is _reliable_** — and the current implementation can't tell you that, as it could change in future versions.  **The language reference documentation** (at kotlinlang.org) can.  JetBrains have said that anything that's part of the published interface, i.e. anything stated in the docs, is stable and won't change in future.  (And hence anything _not_ mentioned there is subject to change, and shouldn't be relied on.)

Comment: You are completely right, docs > current happens-to-be-implementation for sure. I referenced those details because that's what I happened to find yesterday. On second look, I now found proper references to this in the docs, I'll add that to the answer.